# Merging DEM and getting an output with different min/max values than original DEMs

Tags: qgis, dem, merge

I'm trying to merge two DEM into one in QGIS using miscellaneous --> merge. DEM1 has min/max values = 392,111/666,494 and DEM2 = 248,05/1000,64. The problem is that the merged output has right min value but different max value (248,05/926,47). Both original DEM have same data type and same cell size. How could I get some good output considering this issue?

Comment: And same CRS? Can you share the files?

Comment: How are you determining the min/max values?

Comment: Same CRS, but i cant share the files. Regarding min/max values... it's written in the statistics part of the raster's information (properties) and also in the stretched values limits. In addition, when I check the pixels of the dem (the merged one) with highest pixel elevation values, they're actually higher than the maximum values the raster is supposed to contain according to the statistics